# using cache with deferent data depending on parameter with laravel

Tags: laravel, caching

I have data displaied depend on the username written in the URL, and I wanted to cache this data, I have used this way:

```
function info($uname) {

        $info =  Cache::remember('get-all-info'.$uname, env('Cache_DURATION'), function() use($uname){
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $uname)->firstOrFail();
            return $user !=null ? $user->about : null;
        });
        return view('info', compact(['info']));
    }
```

and it is working perfectly.... if I change the username ($uname) the data will return for this specific user...
my question is how does it work? why does data come for a user, not from the cache for a previous user?

is there more than one cache here depending on the user name? or what?
and is this way is good in a matter of performance and speed for either API or normal web application

Comment: i dont understand your question. the "key" used to store in cache is different depending on the user because you have appended the username to the key. you use that key to retrieve the data for that specific user; its a unique key for that user ... on a side note, you don't use `env` outside of config files as if you cache your configuration then `env` calls return `null`

Comment: Do you mean there were different like a files in the cache to store the data depending on the key.... yes I understand now...and for (env) what is the best way to add it for one time?

Comment: caches use keys to store the data, how that is actually stored depends upon the cache and how they implement it, to laravel it is abstracted so it doesn't matter how it actually works on the back end ... there is already a `cache` config file, so you could add an index to that like `'duration' => env('Cache_DURATION')` ... then when you need that value you would use the cache repository: `config('cache.duration')`; this would accommodate the configuration caching